# Graphics drivers malfunctioning

Tags: windows-7, intel-core-i7, high-definition, display-driver

Today I found out that watching youtube videos in window mode 360p, my intel i7 2670qm is showing 10-12% usage. I am pretty concerned about it and I think it is because of intel integrated drivers. Actually I recently installed updated drivers which my laptop reported uncompatible so I uninstalled them and windows automatically reinstalled the intel drivers, the laptop came with.

How can I check if graphics drivers are malfunctioning or not?

Is there any software that can display which program is taking how much memory and cpu, please don't refer me to Task Manager ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [auto-detect](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics) option for Intel will check if your drivers are OK or not. The Intel® Driver Update Utility keeps your system up-to-date. It detects which driver updates are relevant to your computer and then helps you install them quickly and easily.

I would also consider [Process Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for reviewing what is going on. The Process Explorer display consists of two sub-windows. The top window always shows a list of the currently active processes, including the names of their owning accounts, whereas the information displayed in the bottom window depends on the mode that Process Explorer is in: if it is in handle mode you'll see the handles that the process selected in the top window has opened; if Process Explorer is in DLL mode you'll see the DLLs and memory-mapped files that the process has loaded. Process Explorer also has a powerful search capability that will quickly show you which processes have particular handles opened or DLLs loaded.

Comment: Please add a short description for both links provided. This will help in the future if the URLs stop working.

Comment: Does google chrome uses alot of cpu?? Cuz I think playing 360p game trailers should not utilize 10% of the cpu !